# The ext4 file system creation in partition of USB drive failed

Tags: 18.04, usb-drive, ext4

I’m trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 on a 256GB USB flash memory drive which fails with this error: `The ext4 file system creation in partition #2 of /dev/sdc failed.`

See updates below.

Comment: Should say /dev/sdc   (Autocorrect)

Comment: Please 1. describe your computer, brand name and model; 2. describe how you tried to create the ext4 file system. Did you try directly in `/dev/sdc` or in a partition, for example `/dev/sdc1`? Which tool did you use to create the file system? -- Please **edit your original question** to add this information.

Comment: Please post result of "sudo parted /dev/sdc" followed by "print", or "fdisk /dev/sdc" followed by "p"

Comment: id: 
ubuntu
description:  Portable Computer
product:  Inspiron 5521 (Inspiron 5521)
vendor:  Dell Inc.
version:  A14
serial:  67SZ0X1
width:  64 bits
capabilities:  smbios-2.7 dmi-2.7 smp vsyscall32
configuration: 
boot = normal
chassis = portable
family = 103C_5335KV
sku = Inspiron 5521
uuid = 44454C4C-3700-1053-805A-B6C04F305831

Comment: This is the third PC I've tried this on with this usb drive.  The pc is a Windows machine that I boot into Ubuntu using a different usb drive.  Here are the steps I'm taking:  I click on the desktop Install Ubuntu, pick normal installation,  pick erase disk and install Ubuntu, select my generic flash drive (sdc), click install now, continue on the Write the changes to disk.  That's when I get this error: The ext4 file system creation in partition #2 of /dev/sdc failed.

Comment: I just tried both "sudo parted /dev/sdc" and "fdisk /dev/sdc".  This is what I get: cannot open /dev/sdc: No medium found

Comment: It seems the external drive is seen as another device (no longer `/dev/sdc`), so please run the following command lines in order to identify it: `sudo parted -ls` and `sudo lsblk -f` and `sudo lsblk -m` and finally `df -h` to indicate how the computer is booted. Please edit your original question to add this information. Indent each line 4 of the output of the commands 4 spaces in order to render it as 'code'. It will make it easier for us to read, understand and help.

Comment: Is Windows running in UEFI mode (typical for Windows 10 when installed by the manufacturerer) or in BIOS mode (typical for Windows 7)? How is Ubuntu booted (live from USB)? Check when running Ubuntu with `test -d /sys/firmware/efi && echo efi || echo bios`

Comment: fix typing error: Please edit your original question to add this information. Indent each line of the output of the commands 4 spaces in order to render it as 'code'.